# Google Analytics Management API error: User does not have sufficient permissions for this filter

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Sometimes when I try to link a filter to a profile view I get this error `User does not have sufficient permissions for this filter.` with `status=403, code=OK, reason=insufficientPermissions`.

I am using this scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit` and this error does not occur all the time but more or less randomly.

First I create a filter, and then I add it to an account, then I link the filter to a view from the same account.

Is it possible that the added filter is not processed at the moment I add it to a property? I cannot think of any another reason for this error. And it breaks the script :(

Answer (score 0):

Filters are not added to Properties, they are added to Accounts and linked to Views.  Edit permission needs to be granted to your login for the specific Account you are working with or you will get the 403 error. Having Edit permission for the Property or View is not enough.

Comment: In my case I have the correct edit/admin permission for the whole account. I'm also linking filter to a view and add a filter to the account. The problem is that I cannot always reproduce the problem. The tool for which I'm using this is https://www.adwordsrobot.com/en/tools/ga-referrer-spam-killer and I have extended debug output there when an error occurs.

Comment: If you are walking down the account-property-view tree and hitting 403's, I have seen a number of accounts where, even though I have Edit access at the Account level, there is some restriction that prevents access to the property or view/profile level. Permissions are settable at all three levels, so I suspect there is a restriction of some kind in a lower-level entity.???

Comment: The problem and the weird thing is, that it only happens sometimes. Even if I don't change any permission. It is almost like a random error.