# Google Analytics API - inconsistent error "insufficientPermissions' (403)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

**Backgroud:**

I have a PHP code that runs queries to Google Analytics API on behalf of my users.
I am using OAuth2 for authentication and storing the access-tokens of the users in my DB.

My code makes sure not to exceed the quota per user (10 QPS), and I'm using the "quotaUser" parameter in my queries.

**The issue:**

About 50% of my queries to GA are responded with **error 403 ("insufficientPermissions", "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.").**
The strange this is, that the other ~50% are getting the results from GA successfully.

Some important points:

- The only thing common to all the successful queries and common to the unsuccessful queries is the batch that they are in: my code is sending a "batches" of queries (one after one with very short delay between them) to GA's API and every batch is ether passing or failing with 403.
- Adding \ removing permissions to the scope did not solved the issue.
- It is worth mentioning that this is not a View-ID \ Account-ID issue etc. as the same query can pass or fail for the same user and view.
- I saw a related unanswered issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119654/google-analytics-management-api-error-user-does-not-have-sufficient-permissions) and couldn't find any other truly-related issues.

A snippet from my code:

```
//Create a Google Client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile($this->secretJson);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Oauth2::PLUS_LOGIN, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS);

// Set the access token on the client.
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

// Create an authorized analytics service object.
$this->analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

...

//Run the query
$results = $this->analytics->data_ga->get($id, $startDate, $endDate, $metrics, $opts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ido, can you still reproduce this issue? It sounds very much like there is a problem with your access token. I would start troubleshooting by making sure you are setting the same access token for all batch runs and validating that the token is not expired (isAccessTokenExpired()).

Comment: Ilya, the issue is still reproducible. I couldn't find a full solution for the issue but I do think that I found the root cause of it - I believe that for some reason GA is storing the last access token used by my app in some sort of cache. So when sending a request for multiple users with multiple access tokens the access token of the first user is actually being used for all the requests. My workaround was to use the `$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken()` method before creating the `Google_Service_Analytics` of each user.